# How to bind an hidden prototype in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get access to Float32Array on an environment that hides it from me, more precisely, the Khan Academy programming environment.

I saw a guy doing hacky stuff to do a similar thing and I adapted his code, but I don't really understand why I get access to Float32Array by writting the code this way.

***[Code:](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/float32array/6686776618254336)***

```
var Float32Array = (function () {
    return this.Function("return Float32Array;");
})()();

var a = new Float32Array([1, 2, 3]);
```

***Firefox Warning:***

> calling a builtin typed array constructor without new is deprecated and will be forbidden in ES6

***Chrome error***

> Constructor Float32Array requires 'new'

This tells me I'm doing something wrong here, but I don't know what it is. How could I get access to Float32Arrays in a more robust way?

Answer (score 5):

> This tells me I'm doing something wrong here, but I don't know what it is.

No, it just tells you that whatever tool told you that didn't understand your code.

You're not *calling* `Float32Array` without `new`, you're just referring to it.

The code

```
this.Function("return Float32Array;");
```

...called the way it's called in your example (which is loose mode) is creating a function whose body is `return Float32Array;`, like this:

```
function anon() {
    return Float32Array;
}
```

...but it's evaluated at global scope, not local scope.

Your wrapper:

```
var Float32Array = (function() {
})()();
```

...is a function that returns the given function and then immediately calls it. So your `Float32Array` variable ends up being whatever `Float32Array` is at global scope (bypassing shadowing).

---

That said, note that this code is easily fooled. Perhaps it works in the Khan acadamy context, but it could easily be fooled just by assigning to the `Float32Array` property of the global object, or redeclaring it at global scope.

That is, it works here:

```
(function() {
  // Khan academy code
  function Float32Array() {
    console.log("Mine");
  }

  // Your code
  var y = (function() {
    return this.Function("return Float32Array;");
  })()();
  var foo = new y(10);
  console.log("Done", foo);
})();
```

but would fail here:

```
(function() {
  window.Float32Array = function() {
    console.log("Mine");
  };
  var y = (function() {
    return this.Function("return Float32Array;");
  })()();
  var foo = new y(10);
  console.log("Done", foo);
})()
```

or here

```
function Float32Array() {
  console.log("Mine");
}
var y = (function() {
  return this.Function("return Float32Array;");
})()();
var foo = new y(10);
console.log("Done", foo);
```

...because the global symbol is overwritten.

Comment: The tool was Firefox's console. Thanks :D

Comment: @SlySherZ: Interesting, I don't get that warning from Firefox's console. Do you mean Firebug? *Edit:* I don't get it from Firebug either, but we may be on different versions (of Firefox, of Firebug).

Comment: I'm using Vanilla, updated Firefox v43.0.4. No relevant extentions installed.